# Using simple auth without Ember-cli

Tags: ember.js, ember-simple-auth

I want to use **simple auth** without Ember-cli. Up until version 0.8.0, simple auth was distributed as a bower addon, and could be imported with the AMD module inside the bower package (ember-simple-auth/simple-auth.amd.js). Since I want to use the newest version of Ember and Ember Data, I also need to update the simple auth version to version 1.0.1.

How do I use the new version without Ember-cli?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use Ember Simple Auth without Ember CLI anymore.